# Lubridate returns negative MM and SS

Tags: r, lubridate

Performing this basic operation in lubridate:

```
library("lubridate")    
seconds_to_period(10 * 3600) + hours(24) - seconds_to_period(19.67 * 3600)
```

Results:

```
"15H -40M -12S"
```

I was expecting:

```
"14H 19M 48S"
```

Is it normal?

Comment: [This github issue](https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/issues/75) makes it seems like that's not a desired behavior. Maybe file a bug report?

Comment: More on this issue is discussed here: https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/issues/503

Answer (score 1):

We can do the numeric operation on seconds and then apply `seconds_to_period`

```
seconds_to_period((10*3600 + 24*3600) - (19.67 * 3600))
#[1] "14H 19M 48S"
```